# MySQL row lock using FOR UPDATE not working

Tags: mysql

I have a high traffic IVR system that uses MySQL as database server.

When a call is made, I need to select a free representative and LOCK him so no other caller can SELECT him at the same time.

What I'm doing is:

```
SELECT id FROM admins WHERE live = 1 AND available = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
```

The problem is that it's not really working for me. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Note: I am using InnoDB as engine.

Comment: The lock for update means, other processes can not write the record, reading is allowed. Also keep in mind, that read is almost alway allowed when the consistency level is READ_UNCOMMITTED and you might get outdated data using that level. Please read article about this option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: No, you cannot block select. That way lies really slow performance. What you can do is block others from messing with the data while you change it. That is is what the `select ... for update` is for. imo, Don't get concerned that you know it is being changed and all current queries have wrong data. They will learn about later if it is important.

Comment: So, any ideas how to approach this issue where i can't have 2 callers selecting the same free representative?